# Automate the boring stuff with python - The Collatz Sequence

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, collatz-sequence

> ## The Collatz Sequence
>
> Write a function named `collatz()` that has one parameter named `number`.
> If `number` is even, then `collatz()` should print `number // 2` and return
> this value.  If `number` is odd, then `collatz()` should print and return
> `3 * number + 1`.
>
> Then write a program that lets the user type in an integer and that
> keeps calling `collatz()` on that number until the function returns the
> value 1.

```
import sys

def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0: # check's if number is even.
        funNumber = number // 2
        return funNumber
    elif number % 2 == 1: # check's if number is odd.
        funNumber = 3 * number + 1
        return funNumber
        
print('Enter a number:')
try:
    inputNumber = int(input()) # check's if input is an integer.
except:
    print('Enter a number!') # if not an integer program quits.
    sys.exit()
    
whileNumber = collatz(inputNumber) # first function call

while whileNumber != 1: # while loop until function returns 1.
    print(whileNumber)
    whileNumber = collatz(whileNumber)
    if whileNumber == 1: # when number is 1 program ends.
        print(whileNumber)
        break
```

What do you guys think of my solution?

I'm very happy that I did it without cheating - just thinking about the problem and visualising how the code should flow.

I did get stuck on the `whileNumber = collatz(inputNumber)`. At first, that line of code was inside the `while` loop but that just made my entire program freeze. Glad I got it all working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not `input()` without a prompt argument.

You can combine your two modulus operations and the division into one `divmod` call.

Never bare `except`; in this case you're looking for `ValueError`.

Your input validation is correct but would be friendlier as a loop that does not call `exit`.

`whileNumber` should be `while_number` by PEP8.

Consider representing the sequence as an iterator function and only printing at the top level (this violates the letter, but not the spirit, of the requirements).

### Suggested

```py
from typing import Iterator


def collatz(number: int) -> int:
    quotient, is_odd = divmod(number, 2)
    if is_odd:
        return 3*number + 1
    return quotient


def collatz_sequence(start: int) -> Iterator[int]:
    number = start
    while True:
        yield number
        if number == 1:
            break
        number = collatz(number)


def get_start() -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input('Enter a number to start the Collatz sequence: '))
        except ValueError:
            pass


def main() -> None:
    start = get_start()
    for output in collatz_sequence(start):
        print(output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `def main() -> None:` Could you explain what the -> does?

Comment: @JarneVercruysse It's a type hint declaring what the function will return (in this case, nothing).

Answer (score 2):

According to the problem statement, the `collatz()` function should print the number it returns.  I think that's a silly requirement, but us professional programmers sometimes have to implement silly requirements when we can't convince our customers otherwise!

Notice that the statement `return funNumber` is common to both branches of the `if`/`elif`.  That means we can move it outside the condition.  Oh, and the `elif` test can be simply `else` because any integer that's not even has to be odd:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0: # checks if number is even.
        funNumber = number // 2
    else: # it must be odd.
        funNumber = 3 * number + 1
    print(funNumber)
    return funNumber
```

With the printing where we were told to put it, we don't need the `if whileNumber == 1` test in the main program - we can just let the `while` loop do its job normally.

I recommend putting the program logic into a function, and using a *main guard*:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

That will make it easier to reuse parts of your program as a *module* in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function for this many months ago.

### Put everything in functions

Since you already know how to use functions, you should put everything into functions. Your `while` loop belongs in the `Collatz` function, not outside it.

### Put functionality over interactivity

You use `input` and `print` in your code, this is bad, because it hinders performance. Most programmers use functions and arguments instead of interactivity.

Use `return list` instead of printing elements one by one.

Refactored code:

```py
def Collatz(n: int) -> list:
    sequence = [n]
    while n != 1:
        if n % 2:
            n = 3 * n + 1
        else:
            n //= 2
        sequence.append(n)
    return sequence
```

Use like this: `Collatz(9)`

It returns:

```
[9, 28, 14, 7, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

And now this is my actual purpose of the post: Collatz sequence works for negative numbers too. All negative numbers, when building the sequence using the Collatz rule, will inevitably fall into 3 different loops:

```
[
    (-2, -1),
    (-14, -7, -20, -10, -5),
    (
        -50, -25, -74, -37, -110, -55,
        -164, -82, -41, -122, -61, -182,
        -91, -272, -136, -68, -34, -17
    )
]
```

So I made the function to work with negative numbers as well. And I just wanted to post it.

```py
cycles = [
    (4, 2, 1),
    (-2, -1),
    (-14, -7, -20, -10, -5),
    (
        -50, -25, -74, -37, -110, -55,
        -164, -82, -41, -122, -61, -182,
        -91, -272, -136, -68, -34, -17
    )
]
loops = {term: len(cycle) for cycle in cycles for term in cycle}
stops = {term: cycle[-1] for cycle in cycles for term in cycle}

def Collatz(n):
    if not n:
        raise ValueError('n should not be 0')
    
    sequence = [n]
    loop_iter = 0
    looping = False
    while True:
        if not looping and n in loops:
            loop_terms = loops[n]
            looping = True
        
        if looping:
            loop_iter += 1
            if loop_iter == loop_terms:
                break
        
        if n % 2:
            n = 3 * n + 1
        else:
            n //= 2
        
        sequence.append(n)
    
    return sequence
```

It works with every integer, except zero, because if you start with 0 you can never reach anything other than 0 according to the rules.

```
In [22]: Collatz(-9)
Out[22]: [-9, -26, -13, -38, -19, -56, -28, -14, -7, -20, -10, -5]
```